# Inserting data to MySQL via PDO, trying to include a timestamp along with data using an array - getting errors?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a set of data stored in variables, and I want a page to write that data to a MySQL database, I'd like to include the time of insertion, here's my method:

```
$username="username"; $password="password";


try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table01
  (
   Time,
   variable1,
   variable2,
  )

VALUES
  (
    :Time,
    :variable1,
    :variable2,
  )');


  $stmt->execute(array(
        ':Time' => NOW(),
        ':variable1' => $var1,
        ':variable2' => $var2,
  ));

  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

On loading this page, the css is stripped from the page, I get a sort of garbled output of what the page should look like (white screen, plain text some images), additionally on checking the database nothing has been written to it.

Without the Time variable in there, all works perfectly.

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, took me moment to re-read that. You are using the nysql function `now()` to do the work, and as such you don't need to set it as a param and therefore don't need to bind it at all. Just write it into your query.

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table01
  (
   Time,
   variable1,
   variable2,
  )

VALUES
  (
    now(),
    :variable1,
    :variable2,
  )');

  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':variable1' => $var1,
    ':variable2' => $var2,
  ));
```

Edit Re Comment

The `:` in a query denotes it as a parameter in a prepared query. That means you *must* then bind it via the `bind()` command. However if you are inserting the data from *within* the database (such as using a built in function, or pulling the data in from another row) you don't need to declare it in the initial query with `:` and therefore you can't pass it to the query in the bound params array.

Comment: Fantastic - thankyou very much. I had actually taken this approach originally because that's what I thought, however I had written `:now(),` rather than `now(),` in the values and it caused upset. Is it true to say that the colon ":" denotes something which will be bound in an array, and thus if you are putting data directly in via values you don't need it?